# Date counter in Python 3

Tags: python, date, datetime, counter

I want to make a date counter, but I don't want to use `datetime`. I have made a list of the days of the month:

```
monthDays = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

This way, if a month number is input, then I can search through the list for the same number and find the corresponding amount of days in that month e.g. `monthDays[7]` will find me `31`.

The input of my date is of the form: `dd/mm/yyyy`, so I just use `date[0:2]` to extract the date ... and so on. First I check if the input date is in the future - fine.

Then I say, if the month is equal to today's month and the year is equal to today's year, then the difference is just the difference of the two day values.

I'm seriously a little bit stuck from here...

I've got, if today's month is less than or equal to the input month AND today's year is equal to the input year, then the elapsed days is the sum of:

- the days left in the current month; and
- the days between today's month and the input month

taken away from:

- the difference of the two day values.

Can anybody help from here onwards? I want to be able to calculate the days elapsed between today and ANY date in the future.

Comment: "I want to make a date counter, but I don't want to use datetime." I'm wondering if this is some kind of homework with that restrictin or just a bad idea. If you want to write a date counter, you are using the datetime module. It's its purpose. Don't reinvent the wheel. Dates are tricky, you can't just reimplement this.

Comment: what about leap years?

Comment: also what about leap years?

Comment: Yes, I plan to add a function that returns some kind of boolean value for a year argument indicating whether it's a leap year or not.

Answer (score 1):

If the date is after the current year, then you'll need to calculate the number of days left in this year, then, the number of days into the new year of the new date and any whole years inbetween.

Don't forget, monthDays[2] can be 28 or 29, depending on the year. Leap years are identified by years where:

- The year is evenly divisible by 4;
- If the year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless;
- The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

(Source: http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html)